# Error bars are the same for facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some error bars.

Code:

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(c("Data"),each=6),
           Legend=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
           low=c(2832,3192,2307,3457,2171,6222),
           high=c(3561,3585,2561,3457,2171,6222),
           sdlow=c(465,474,330,1244,950,4218),
           sdhigh=c(550,519,347,1244,950,4218))

df2<-melt(df,id=c("x","Legend","sdlow","sdhigh"))


p<-ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x,y=value,fill = Legend)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
facet_wrap(~variable)+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sdlow, ymax=value+sdlow), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
#geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=high-sdhigh, ymax=high+sdhigh), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))

p
```

Problem: The error bars for `high`are the same as for `low`. But three error bars have to be different. 
I think my error in reasoning is in `df2`.

The plot show two windows `low`and `high`. The error bars of `A`,`B`,`c` have to be different. The problem is that in the `high` window are the same error bars as in the `low` window for `A`,`B`,`c`. It's difficult to recognize because values are similar.

Comment: What do you mean that they should be different? Your data shows that low/high range is the same (`value` is different for low and high, but this is shown in plot).

Comment: Hello again :-), The first three values of `sdlow`and `sdhigh`are different. That are my error bars.

Comment: I am still not sure where is the error in the plot.

Comment: @Hark, yes, and this is represented by bars (not error bars - they are the same) :-)

Comment: @Hark, i think the confusion is in how you named the columns. It seems that `sdlow` is the sd for low and and sdhigh is sd for high. You probably need to add sd column : `df2$sd <- ifelse(df2$variable=="low", df2$sdlow,df2$sdhigh)` and then `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))`

Comment: Yes `sdlow = standard deviation low = error bar`, `sdhigh = standard deviation high = error bar`

Comment: @Marcelo. Great it works. Now I'm trying to understand your code:-)